# Modular programming and functions prototypes

Tags: c, c99

I am learning C on this (French) site: http://openclassrooms.com/courses/apprenez-a-programmer-en-c  and I am at the chapter on modular programming that says:

> Because the order has real importance here: if you put your function before the main in your source code, your computer has read it and knows it. When you will make a call to the function the computer will know the function and know where to go get it.
>
> However, if you put your function after the main, it will not work because the computer does not know the function yet. Try it and see!

I tried to put my function after the main function as in the following code, yet my code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int nbE = 0;
    int nbM = 0;
    printf("Nombre a tripler : ");
    scanf("%d", &nbE);
    nbM = triple(nbE);
    printf("Le nombre triple de %d est %d", nbE, nbM);
 
    return 0;
}
 
int triple(int nb)
{
    return nb * 3;
}
```

Can you explain why it's working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because the compiler assumes the arguments and return value are `int`, which they are. If your function returned a `float` value, it would not work properly. This is why function prototypes are used: to declare the function (say in a header file) so it can be properly used without the body being seen by the compiler building this module. The body might be in another file, or in a library. So you should have

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int triple(int nb);      // <-- function prototype

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { ...
```

at the top of your program. But it is not necessary to put the whole function before `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is probably being compiled according to an older C standard, which doesn't require prototypes. Instead, it assumes any undeclared function it sees called takes whatever arguments it's passed, and returns `int`.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile with warning options (-Wall), which you should always do, then you will see that the compiler is *guessing* the existence of the function by creating an implicit declaration for it.

Generally you do not want the compiler guessing your function declarations, because it could get them wrong. Stay safe and always declare your functions in advance.

Answer (score -2):

Program doesn't contains function prototype declaration.
.
There should be an:

```
int triple(int);
```